# Kotlin vs Java : What to choose when starting a new Flutter project?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

When starting a new Flutter project in Android Studio, it gives you the choice of android language between Java or Kotlin. so the question is:

**Is my choice affecting any type of performance or compatibility? Application size or Error-handling ? Is there any difference at all ?**

Same goes for Objective-C vs Swift ?

Comment: I have heard when someone who knows Java learns Kotlin, they will not look back to write code in Java again (unless they have to)...  
So, go for Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My Recommended is to Go for `kotlin` in `Android`. and For `IOS` go for `Swift`**

One of the best reason is `Google` and `Apple` recommended and preferred this languages.

Second things `kotlin` is very `optimized language` so it's reduce the codes and make your dart file more clear to understand.

Third things `kotlin supports multiple platforms`. where `java` have some `limitations` in it.

But at the end both of the language is very useful to developed a single app.

**Note : If you start for Application development in native Android, First Go for Java language then you have to learn about kotlin.** **because `Java is a Base of Native Android`**

Answer (score 2):

Use

> Android -> Kotlin
>
> IOS -> Swift

because these are the languages ​​that apple and google recommend.

Answer (score 2):

Pick Kotlin and Swift as they are the newer and more preferred languages of those platforms

Although it really doesn't matter. You won't use either of those languages much. You will mostly interact with Dart

Answer (score 1):

Use Kotlin for Android and Swift for IOS. In Editor you would be using Dart.